# JQuery access dynamically created objects

Tags: jquery, click

How can I acceess objects(divs) that were dynamically generated.
I mean DIVS that were not present in output when `$(document).ready(function()` started.

If I do:

```
$('#click_me').click(function() {
    $('#container').append('<div id="clicker2">can you click on me?</div>');
});

$('#clicker2').click(function() {
    alert('hurray, it works');
});
```

the clicker2 won't work

How can I fix it?
I'm intent to create more than one dynamically.  and I want to assign Jquery actions to themt too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.click() functions that aren't working on spans or divs that are added later, you'll need to use [.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

```
$("#clicker2").live("click", function(){
  # do stuff to spans currently existing
  # and those that will exist in the future
});
```

Comment: well my actions get duplicated as well !!!! :(
when I do APPEND  and then assign action to it. 
next time I do append and assing action 
when action is fired up.. it runs twice

Answer (score 1):

Create the div explicity and assemble its attributes and events before you append it.

```
var $div = $('<div />').append('can you click on me?').attr('id', 'clicker2').click(function() {
alert('hurray, it works');
});
$('#container').append($div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the click binding inside the first click function:

```
$('#click_me').click(function() 
{
    $('#container').append('<div id="clicker2">can you click on me?</div>');
    $('#clicker2').click(function(){  alert('hurray, it works');   });
});
```

As you have it, the binding is being called, but there is no "div#clicker2" to bind to the second function.

Hope this helps.