# Using JQuery for a template and it's not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

Let me start off by saying I know this is probably not the correct way to do this, but I am sure someone will point me in the right direction :)

**Project Background**

What I am trying to achieve is this; I have an index page on my root and four php pages - about, contact, location, and faq's - that reside in a folder called external. When the index page loads it will display four check boxes - about, contact, location, and faq's. When one of the check boxes get checked a div will slide down and show the contents of the corresponding php page via load(). The user will now have the option to add or remove elements of the php page to customize and taylor to their needs. Once the user completes the editing they simply click the done button and php spits out another php file with the changes so the user can download the file.

Stay with me here :), so basically the idea here is to have a barebones file that the user can change to fit their needs and will be able to download for their use once editting is complete.

**Problem**

When the external php page is loaded the css works fine, but the JQuery does not work on the external page. I suspect it is due to the fact I am using one JQuery file that is called in my index file and there is some type of scope issue when I try to use it with elements in the external file. An example would be, when I try to access a link within the contact.php the query function will not work. Keep in mind the contact.php page is called in via load().

**Files**

Note: I understand I need to be more descriptive with my naming convention in regards to my divs, the css files is what I was told to use and I was not to make a different one :(

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CR8&#1071;</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="library/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="library/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="w">
<div id="mh"><p>CR8&#1071;</p></div>
<div id="mc">
    <div id="pc">
        <div id="h"><p>STEP 1 : Select pages to build</p><a href="#">UNCHECK ALL</a></div>
        <div id="cb-c">
            <div id="cb-c-r1">
                <form name="f">
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="index"/><label>Index Page: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="contact"/><label>Contact Page: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="about"/><label>About Page: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="calender"/><label>Calender Page: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="news"/><label>News Page: </label></li>
                </ul>
                </form> 
            </div>
            <div id="cb-c-r2">
                <form>
                <ul> 
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="image"/><label>Image Gallery: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="testimonials"/><label>Testimonials Page: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="faqs"/><label>Faq's Page: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="links"/><label>Links Page: </label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="index" value="products"/><label>Products Page: </label></li>
                </ul> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>   
        </div>
        <div id="pc">
               <div id="h"><p>Step 2 : Page options</p></div>
            <div id="output-container"></div>
```

**jquery.js**

```
$(function()
{
    $('#h a').click(function()
    {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#output-container img').remove();
        $('#output-container').children().slideUp(function()
        {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('input:checkbox').click(function()
    {
        var cb = $(this).attr('value');
        var active = false;

        $('#test-link').live('click',function()
        {
            alert('It Worked :)');
        });

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $('#output-container').append('<div id="'+cb+'-container" class="container"><div id="container-header-'+cb+'" class="container-header"><p>'+cb+'</p></div></div>');
            $('#output-container div:first-child').css('border-top','none');
            $('#'+cb+'-container').hide().slideToggle('slow',function()
            {
                $('#container-header-'+cb).append($('<img>',{src:'graphics/add_item.png',id:'expand-'+cb}));
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#expand-'+cb).remove();
            $('#'+cb+'-container').slideToggle(function()
            {
                $(this).remove();
            });
         }                
         $('#container-header-'+cb).click(function()
         {        
             if(!active)
             {
                 $('#'+cb+'-container').append('<div id="option-pane-'+cb+'" class="option-pane"></div>');
                 $('#option-pane-'+cb).load('external/'+cb+'.php', function() 
                 {
                     $('#option-pane-'+cb).hide().slideToggle('slow',function()
                     {
                         $('#container-header-'+cb+' img').attr("src","graphics/remove_item.png");
                     });
                  });
                  active = true;
              }
              else
              {
                  $('#option-pane-'+cb).slideToggle('slow',function()
                  {
                      $(this).is(':visible')?$('#container-header-'+cb+' img').attr("src","graphics/remove_item.png"):$('#container-header-'+cb+' img').attr("src","graphics/add_item.png");
                  });
               }
          });
    });
});
```

**contact.php** (I am grabbed one file to demonstrate)

```
<div class="emc">
<?php
//print('testing');
?>
<label>Select Amount of Text Sections</label><br />
    <select>
    <option>Select ...</option>
    <option value="1">1 Section</option>
    <option value="2">2 Sections</option>
    <option value="3">3 Sections</option>
    <option value="4">4 Sections</option>
    </select><br /><br />
<p>Once the user selects the amount of text sections and desired contact fields, jquery will populate the amount of required header and text area sections for the user to fill-in desired text. Once complete the user will click submit jquery will post all information to a controller.php and a front-end, back-end, and MySQL file will be created.</p><br /><br />
<a href="#" id="test-link">Test Link</a>
</div>
```

If I need to clarify anything or I am just completely losing people, let me know and I will try to better my question. Thanks in advance for any feedback :)

Comment: tl;dr. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: @Orbit -  `$('#test-link').click(function() ...` in the JQuery file does not work on my external file called in. Does that help?

Comment: Hmmm... not sure how I can say it any other way. I applogize :(

Comment: You need to continue narrowing down the issue. This is _far_ too much code to debug a single issue. The vast majority can almost certainly be abstracted away. You should end up with a 10-20 line testcase. Of course by then you'll probably have found the problem in the process -- it's called debugging :)

Comment: Yeah it is a ton of code, let me try and adjust it. Thanks :)

Comment: I removed the css to lighten the code up. I think the rest of the code should be present so everyone can see every element of the project.

Comment: It looks like the reason it's not being called is because the `contact` page is being called after jQuery loads, so jQuery doesn't 'see' the `#test-link`. Try looking at [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for jQuery. Something like `$('#test-link').on('click',function(){Your code...});`

Comment: Keep going. If we can see every element of the project then you haven't done any narrowing down of the issue. You should end up with a 10-20 line testcase. This is a site for questions about programming languages, rather than a pair programming meeting place. :)

Comment: @John - Thank you for your response, but no joy. I tried inside the click event of the checkbox and out side.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit -  I do appreciate your help in trying to lighten up my code for others to see, but I still think that in this case where I didn't know the precise location of the issue all the code was required. The answer has been addressed and I would urge others to follow the same proceedure as I so others can have everything required to help "debug" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its not working is that click function won't work on dom elements added after the page load. You need to use the live function. Please check out the answer here: [JQuery access dynamically created objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519515/jquery-access-dynamically-created-objects)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I had to put it inside the click event of the checkbox, but non the less live() is the only thing that worked. Thank you so much :)