# jQuery Ajax form submit disregards 'success' function, reloads page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm submitting an html form to a mySQL db with jQuery .ajax.  When I submit the form (after all the fields are validated), the data IS inserted as a new record into the db, but the success function doesn't run.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/u3C4U/)

*This is all taking place in a google maps infoWindow, but I'm not sure that that's relevant.

HTML:

```
<div id="formDiv">
    <form name="htmlForm" id="htmlForm">

    <p id="contactP">
    <label for="contact">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"/> <br/>
    </p>

    <p id="phoneP">
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/> <br/>
    </p>

    <p id="datepickerP">
    <label for="datepicker">Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker"/> <br/>
    </p>

    <p id="latP">
    <label for="lat">Latitude:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="location"/> <br/>
    </p>

    <p id="lngP">
    <label for="lng">Longitude:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" class="location"/> <br/>
    </p>        

    <p id="descP">
    <label for="desc" id="dos">Description of Sighting:</label> <br/>
    <textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea><br/>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" class="button" id="submitBtn" value="Post Sighting!" onClick="postSighting();"/>

</div>
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
function postSighting() {
    // jQuery Validate
    $('#htmlForm').validate({
        rules: {
            contact: {required:true, email:true},
            phone: {required:true},
            date: {required:true, date:true},
            lat: {required:true},
            lng: {required:true},
            desc: {required:true},
        },
        messages: {
            desc: 'Please be descriptive!'
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo($('#' + element.attr('id') + 'P'));
            return false;
        };
    });

    //jQuery ajax form submit
        var contact = $('input#contact').val(),
            phone = $('input#phone').val(),
            date = $('input#datepicker').val(),
            lat = $('input#lat').val(),
            lng = $('input#lng').val(),
            desc = $('textarea#desc').val();
        var dataString = "contact=" + contact + '&phone=' + phone + "&date=" + date + "&lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&desc=" + desc;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Includes/test.php",
            data: dataString,
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(ajaxOptions);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                return $('#htmlForm').validate().form();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#formDiv').html('<div id="message"></div>');
                $('#message').html('<h2>Thank You!</h2>')
                    .append('<h3>Your sighting has been reported</h3>')     
                return false;
            }   
        });
        return false;  
    };
```

I've alerted out the jQuery ajax errors, and I'm getting:

alert(xhr); =>  0

alert(thrownError) => error

http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/u3C4U/

Comment: What do you see with firebug?

Comment: What do you expect, your success function starts with return false, is that not what it's supposed to do ? If so place the return false at the bottom of the success function!

Comment: is there any chance to get a repro @ jsfiddle ... otherwise it's like fishing around ...

Comment: @Andreas http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/u3C4U/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of the inline javascript function:

```
$("#map_canvas").on('click', '.submitBtn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    postSighting();        
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that, it got mixed up in the shuffle.  Same result tho -- Reloads the current page.

Comment: Are you preventing the default action of the submit button?

Comment: That's what the return false is doing

Comment: @Roy -  It's all dynamic, you will have to delegate the events to the parent element. Edited my answer, could be other things that will need updating to delegated events, and you should try this on a webserver where the Ajax function will work, not on JSfiddle.

Comment: I'm not familiar with an online editor that supports webserver (this is my first php project). Suggestion?

Comment: Test it on a local webserver, any LAMP, XAMP, WAMP thingy should do?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery can not attach to the submit button, as it has the *id* submitBtn and you try to attach to *class* submitBtn.

Change from:

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    postSighting();        
});
```

to:

```
$('#submitBtn').live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    postSighting();        
});
```

Also note the use of [`.live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) because the form is [created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519515/jquery-access-dynamically-created-objects).

Comment: e.preventDefault(); //  This should already prevent the default 'submit' action of the button, shouldn't it?

Comment: I caught that in his post and made the correction, thanks tho.

Comment: Attaching to the click-event on the #map_canvas may or may not be successful, depending on how fast the popup ist generated. The usage of `.live()` makes sure, that events will be attached to all elements matching the selector – even if they are created later (like your form).